# Dependencies between generic classes

Tags: java, generics

I have the following Interfaces:

```
public interface Assembler<T, S> {
   S assemble( T val);
}

public interface Slicer<T, V> {
   V[] slice(T val);
}
```

I want to have an Assembler instance use a Slicer instance and call it’s slice(). I have the following:

```
public class MyAssembler<T, S> implements Assembler<T, S> {

   private final Slicer<T, V> slicer;

   //ctor
   public MyAssembler() {
     slicer = new MySlicer<T, V>();
   }

   @Override
   public S assemble(T val) {         
      V[] v = mySlicer.slice(val);
    }
```

This doesn’t compile because the V type is not known (cannot be resolved to a type) in MyAssembler. I cannot change the Assembler interface to be `Assembler<T, S, V>`. Is there another way I can define the dependency? This is not an issue with non generic classes. Even if a static factory method is used to get the reference to Slicer, the problem of unknown V would still exist. Any suggestions? If this cannot be done, can anyone recommend a different approach or design pattern that allows for an Assembler to call the Slicer's slice()?

Comment: You can declare a third type variable for `MyAssembler`.

Comment: I tried that by using `MyAssembler<T, S, V>`. It compiles, but once attempting to instantiate, e.g.: `Assembler<Integer, Integer, Integer> asmblr = new MyAssembler<Integer, Integer, Integer>` it fails compilation with: incorrect number of arguments for type Assembler<T,S>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer, Integer, Integer>.

Comment: The third type argument is necessary for `MyAssembler`, not for the declared type, `Assembler`. But it doesn't seem very useful here, as you don't do anything with `V`.

Comment: In the real use case, assume V will be used.

Comment: You won't be able to use through it a reference of type `Assembler` however.

Comment: exception1's answer of reusing a type param may solve this issue.

Comment: I misunderstood your comment. Yes, `Assembler<Integer, Integer> asmblr = new MyAssembler<Integer, Integer, Integer>' compiles fine. In this case, I can add and use V in MyAssembler.

Comment: The `V` is fine in `MyAssembler`, but you aren't interacting with the `MyAssembler` through the `MyAssembler` interface, you're interacting with it through the `Assembler` interface (interface used as the visible methods, not as an `interface`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting Sotirios Delimanolis' comment as the answer.

To allow for the use of V in MyAssembler, declare `MyAssembler<T, S, V> extends Assembler<T, S>`. To use it, instantiate with for ex: `Assembler<Integer, Integer> asmblr = new MyAssembler<Integer, Integer, Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

**Inheritance** will solve your problem instead of **Composition** in this case as shown below:

```
public class MyAssembler<T,S,V> extends MySlicer<T,V> implements Assembler<T,S> {

    public MyAssembler() {
    }

    @Override
    public S assemble(T val) {
        V[] v = this.slice(val);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will Assembler **always** have Slicer as one of its two generics? If so, you only need to define one generic, and have the Slicer as a non-generic member variable.

If, however, the generic types may or may not be Slicer, you can implement special handling for when one of them *is* Slicer with reflection, especially `if (v instanceof Slicer)` and then casting to Slicer if true.

Comment: The Slicer will not be one of the generic types T or S in Assembler.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `S` and `V` are generic, you can exchange them for any other type, even other generics. You can do:

```
public class MyAssembler<T, S> implements Assembler<T, S> {

    private final Slicer<T, S> slicer;

    public MyAssembler() {
        slicer = new MySlicer<T, S>();
    }

    @Override
    public S assemble(T val) {
        S[] v = slicer.slice(val);
        return v[0]; // for example
    }
}
```

What I did is to define `T` and `S` as the same type. In my own implementation, I can do this without problems.

Comment: This may work assuming the types will always be the same, but doesn't this limit the S and original V to now be the same type? May want the Assember S to be String, and the Slicer V to be Integer.

Comment: Indeed. But as you indicated, the Assembler shall *call Slicer's slice()*. If the types S and V are different, you can't guarantee anything. How do you want to cast the `V´ to `S`? By calling `slice` you have a `V`, but inside `assemble` you want to return `S`. You can't do that if you want support arbitrary types. But: as shown in my example, you can't choose the type of Slicer. It will be determined by the type of assembler. Since slicer is well encapsulated, you will not even know that there is behind the assembler that does the work. You just use Assembler which behaves like a black box.

Comment: I think it is more flexible now to use V in Assembler as such: `MyAssembler<T, S, V> extends Assembler<T, S>`.